# Elastic Search _suggest caching

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch to power both my main search engine and as an autocomplete tool.
I use version "1.0.1"

My problem : there seem to be a pretty persistant cache on the suggester and I can't get rid of it.

I have dropped all my mappings, restarted everything, so when I do

```
GET /myindex/film/_search
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 10000,
  "fields": ["title"]
}
```

I get an empty result and I am fairly satisfied with that.

BUT when I send this request :

```
GET /myindex/_suggest
{
  "hits" : {
    "text" : "south",
    "completion" : {
        "size" : 90,
        "field" : "suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

I get many results of type "film" !

How is that possible ? How can I get rid of them ?

Comment: are you sure that this is not a http/browser whatever problem? how are you calling elasticsearch?

Comment: I'm calling it from Sense (marvel plugin) for testing, but I just tried and the same occur when calling it with a curl command from shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

`POST /myindex/_optimize`

or if you're worried about performance

`POST /myindex/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true`

as stated here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing (in the note that leads there https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the data directory as suggested by @andy. Just delete the index and recreate one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper method for suggestors in elasticsearch.I have already faced the same issue at that I dropped the index and recreated it.By default it is taking cache for suggestors.

My suggestion is drop the index and recreate it.